# The text in the command prompt is no longer visible

Tags: cmd

I have played with the colorsettings for the cmd text a little bit, but now the textcolor is fixed on black (a bit problematic in a black background) and it seems I cannot change it in text color settings. Does anyone know how to fix this? [image: ...]

Comment: Type `color f4`. Right click titlebar - Properties - and set the colours you want.

Comment: It works partially, I have to type this every time I open the cmd, and both the properties and defaults tabs do not react to changes; it is an improvement though

Comment: See if you have a color command running at cmd's start at HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor

Comment: And the value name is `AutoRun`.

Comment: I could not find the Command Processor option in that path

Comment: `ctrl+f` gave me AutoRun in the office path

Comment: Follow @Mark's advice again (`Right click titlebar - Properties - and set the colours you want.`), but with `Defaults` instead of `Properties`.

Comment: Nothing to do with Office's Autorun value.

Comment: What happens if you type `cmd` in Run dialog (Winkey+R).

Comment: I get a `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe command` prompt instead of the normal one. Also, when I type `start` in the normal cmd, `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe command` opens, with textcolor of my choice; thank you very much!